# Web Api shared DTOs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am building a few mvc 4.0 web api services on an internal network.  I have come from a WCF WSHttp background where we shared common DTOs and a contract between the Service and the client.

With web api should I share dtos between client and service? Or is that bad practice and I should just let the client try and deserialize the json to whatever object structure it wants to. 
Which in my case may lead to duplicate dtos at the client and service?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently working on an n-tire web project and our DTOs are stored in a publicly accessible library that the service layer and MVC website use. We found this to make the most logical sense and it stops duplication whilst still maintaining a layer of separation.

I hope that helps and good luck!

Comment: i was going down the path of separate dto's at either end (and a bit of duplication), but i am wondering now if this is sensible

Comment: Just wondering if anyone has the other perspective and has a strong argument for keeping them totally separate. thanks